# PPT Timestamp Autoupdate with formatting

Tags: powerpoint

In ppt we can possible create a footer timestamp, however what I need is just 'mmm YYYY', which is not provided by the ppt default options. Is it possible to access it and type in my own formatstring? Many Thanks.

Comment: it's still unsolved, as I'm seeking for being capable to add another option under the update automatically, not just fixed date which I can type it in myself to avoid all these fuss. Steve's answer is closer to what I want but it obviously is not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2013, go to `INSERT` tab, then select `Header & Footer`, then you will see a dialog like this:

[image: header & footer dialog]

Here you should tick `Date and time`, then choose `Fixed` and edit your own footer, then select `Apply to All`.

After this, you will see all your slides are embedded with your own footer, a sample is attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Header and Footer dialog box, when you put a check next to Date and time and choose Update automatically, the first choice on the dropdown listbox is the Windows short date format.  If you customize this in Control Panel to mmmm YYYY, it will show August 2014 in PowerPoint.

Of course this will only work on your system.  When you move it to another computer, it'll use that computer's default short date format.